Export Excel cell values to Word
I want to paste an Excel table & some other cell values into Word. The macro copies the table, but not the other cell values.
I inserted respective Bookmarks in Word to export the data.
I checked the "Reference" ==> "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library"
Sub ExcelTablesToWord()

    Dim tbl As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    On Error GoTo WordDocNotFound
    Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Documents.Open ("D:\Template.docx")
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents("D:\Template.docx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With myDoc.Bookmarks("HeaderSubject").Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range("B8").Value
    End With
    With myDoc.Bookmarks("REF_ID").Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range("B4").Value
    End With
    With myDoc.Bookmarks("Date").Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range("B5").Value
    End With
    With myDoc.Bookmarks("PersonName").Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range("B7").Value
    End With
    With myDoc.Bookmarks("MainSubject").Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range("B8").Value
    End With
    
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range("A14:G41")
    tbl.Copy
    
    'Paste Table into MS Word (using inserted Bookmarks -> ctrl+shift+F5)
    myDoc.Bookmarks("table").Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False
    
    With myDoc.Bookmarks("T_C").Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range("B10").Value
    End With
    
    
    'Completion Message
    MsgBox "Copy/Pasting Complete!", vbInformation
    GoTo EndRoutine
    
    'ERROR HANDLER
WordDocNotFound:
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word file 'Excel Table Word Report.docx' is not currently open, aborting.", 16
    
    'Put Stuff Back The Way It Was Found
EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub



With clause is misused in your code.
Open method returns a Document object. Two lines could be combined as

Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("D:\Template.docx")

Microsoft documentation:

With statement


Documents.Open method (Word)

Sub ExcelTablesToWord()
    Dim tbl As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo WordDocNotFound
    Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    WordApp.Visible = True
    ' WordApp.Documents.Open ("D:\Template.docx")
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("D:\Template.docx")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing")
        myDoc.Bookmarks("HeaderSubject").Range.Text = .Range("B8").Value
        myDoc.Bookmarks("REF_ID").Range.Text = .Range("B4").Value
        myDoc.Bookmarks("Date").Range.Text = .Range("B5").Value
        myDoc.Bookmarks("PersonName").Range.Text = .Range("B7").Value
        myDoc.Bookmarks("MainSubject").Range.Text = .Range("B8").Value
        Set tbl = .Range("A14:G41")
        tbl.Copy
        'Paste Table into MS Word (using inserted Bookmarks -> ctrl+shift+F5)
        myDoc.Bookmarks("table").Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
        myDoc.Bookmarks("T_C").Range.Text = .Range("B10").Value
    End With
    'Completion Message
    MsgBox "Copy/Pasting Complete!", vbInformation
    GoTo EndRoutine
    'ERROR HANDLER
WordDocNotFound:
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word file 'Excel Table Word Report.docx' is not currently open, aborting.", 16
    'Put Stuff Back The Way It Was Found
EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

